# Where does GDB store its general register layout?

Tags: arm, gdb, cortex-m, gdbserver

I'm building my own GDB Server instance based on the Remote Protocol.

One command sent by GDB is 'g', which reads general registers. The layout of the response to this command is architecture specific (in my case I'm targeting armv8-m.main).

Where can I find the register layout information necessary to reconstruct a response to this command?

Comment: The [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html#Packets) says "The size of each register and their position within the ‘g’ packet are determined by the GDB internal gdbarch functions DEPRECATED_REGISTER_RAW_SIZE and gdbarch_register_name."  So maybe you want to look those up in the gdb source code.

Comment: Your question is really "where does GDB *document* its general register layout, right?
GDB's own handling of this is found in https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gdb/arm-tdep.c

Answer (score 1):

After further digging, register definitions are found within xml profile files within "gdb\features\your_arch" e.g. "gdb\features\arm\arm-m-profile.xml".

These translate directly to the format used within the 'g' response, with padding for any registers not explicitly mentioned between the first and last entry.